Raspberry Pi 4 doesn't show anything on screen a short while after installing the OS
I installed the 64-bit Raspberry Pi OS onto a Raspberry Pi 4B model very recently. Everything worked fine, I installed vscode in it and updated the libraries. However, after shutting it down once, I can't seem to get it to switch on again. Nothing shows up on the monitor at all. I tried using different HDMI ports and even trying a different SD card with a different OS installed. Nothing seems to work. Is this an issue with the hardware itself? I also noticed that when I power up the device, I only see the red light switching on. The green one does not come on at all.
UPDATE: I want to add that I plugged in a USB-C type cable for power and once the OS booted up, I connected a dell docking station to one of the USBs. The system still worked fine but the problem comes up when I try to start the system again. I feel like maybe the docking station might have something to do with this problem.

So, the pi no longer boots, even with a freshly installed Raspberry Pi OS bookworm? Have you tried the lite version too? Do you get any output to monitor at all even with no SD card installed?

I haven't tried the lite version but I did try the same Raspberry Pi with different SD cards and got the same response. So I'm guessing it has nothing to do with the OS.

try a USB thumb drive - perhaps the sd reader is borked

I feel like maybe the docking station might have something to do with this problem. so, does it boot if you don't have the docking station connected

@JaromandaX when I disconnect the docking station and use the Raspberry Pi, the problem still persists, but if I use a new Raspberry Pi that was never connected to the docking station, it works fine. Any Raspberry Pi that was connected to the docking station does not work anymore. The red light stays on and nothing shows up on the monitor. I am not sure why connecting a docking station while having a separate power supply would damage a Raspberry Pi.

How many Raspberry Pi's have you destroyed using this Docking Station!!!
